# Javascript condition input id statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, jquery-selectors

ihave this code working perfectly, to simulate a prefill input field with an image :

```
<script>
$('#example).focus(function(){
    var newValue = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).val() == ""){
        $(this).css("background-image", "none");
    }else{
        $(this).val(newValue);
    }
}).blur(function(){
    var newValue = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).val() == ""){
             $(this).css("background-image", "url(assets/templates/herveou-coiffure/css/pre_input.png)");
}else{
        $(this).val(newValue);
    }
});
</script>
```

The thing i need to use this with few input field (at least 2) so i tried something like this :

```
<script>
$('#example, example2').focus(function(){
    var newValue = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).val() == ""){
        $(this).css("background-image", "none");
    }else{
        $(this).val(newValue);
    }
}).blur(function(){
    var newValue = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).val() == ""){
       if ($('#example2')[0]){
   // Do something here if an element with this class exists
 $(this).css("background-image", "url(assets/templates/herveou-coiffure/css/headers.jpg)");}
       if ($('#example')[0]){
   // Do something here if an element with this class exists
 $(this).css("background-image", "url(assets/templates/herveou-coiffure/css/pre_input.png)");}
}else{
        $(this).val(newValue);
    }
});
</script>
```

Of course i'm not a javascritp expert and it does not work, anyone can help ??
Thank you very much...

Comment: The question is how to use this with few input fields background image ?

Comment: You can't just change the question 2 hours later like that and invalidate everyone's answers! If you have a new problem, accept the answer for this question, and ask a new one.

Comment: The question has always been the same, you just misanderstood it. "The thing is, i need to use this with few input field (at least 2)..." Now calm down, it is a matter of comprehension, you can read my first post again and again, nothing has changed. If someone give me the right answer i will give him my vote.

Comment: No, I did not misunderstand anything. You tried to edit `$('#example, #example2')` into your code, which is the correct answer which I have given you as to why you could not use the code on two elements with different ID's. Nothing has changed because I've rolled back your edit because you cannot put my answer into your question and invalidate everyone's answers like that.

Comment: Is the code working now ??? No! so what, you want me to vote for something that does not works ?? Make it works and you will have my vote.

Comment: Have you got some HTML for me or a jsFiddle? I can do it right now if so :)

Comment: Ok thank you very much : http://jsfiddle.net/sutrah/35JMC/16/ o when the page loads everything is ok, there is two different backgrounds. But on focus the second field whithout fill anything and then blur the background is now the same as the first field. It is hard for me to explain, hope you'll understand.

Comment: Is this what you wanted - http://jsfiddle.net/35JMC/18/

Comment: You are the man! Thanks a lot you deserve your vote ;) My apologies for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you are selecting an ID, you need to remember to use the ID selector `#`.

You need to use `$('#example, #example2')` instead of `$('#example, example2')`.

Answer (score 0):

When you write  `$('<selector1>, <selector2> , ....'`. You should write the appropriate selector in each parameter. So You should change `$('#example, example2')` to be `$('#example, #example2').`

Comment: Why post another answer instead of just upvoting the correct one?

Comment: Ok you are right, i made a mistake when i copied the code, it was already like that. But the real question is how can i have background image on blur "headers.jpg" for #example2 and "pre_input.png" for #example ?